# $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{x+1-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} = 2$ and not $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{x+1-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$$

If we multiply by $\dfrac xx$ then we get

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = 1+ 0 - \sqrt{1+0} = 0$

But the limit should be $2$.

First question:
We got the limit to $2$ by seperating $x<0$ and $x>0$. However, I do not understand why we can't divide by $x$.

Second question:
How can we calculate the limit

Comment: multiply by $$\frac{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: @Alessandro, you are wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I see now

Comment: A remark: you're not "multiplying by $x/x$" (in fact, I'm not even sure what you mean here). What you're doing is splitting the fraction in parts
$$ \frac{x+1-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} =\frac{x}{x}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} $$
and as $x\to-\infty$, you're correct that the first terms tend to $1$ and $0$. What Yves and I have tried to tell you is that you are mistaken about the third term.

Comment: Your error boils down to thinking that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. That identity is true for *positive* $x$, but not when $x$ is negative. The correct identity in general is $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\dfrac{x+1-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1x-\dfrac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{\left|x\right|}\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)=\quad$ ( because $\;x<0\;$)

$=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1x+\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2}}\right)=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1x+\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{x^2}}\right)=$

$=1+0^-+\sqrt{1+0^+}=$

$=1+1=2\;.$

Comment: So everytime we want to put a negative number under a square root, we must first make it absolute value ? In line 3.

Comment: Yes, we must first make it absolute value, indeed we cannot put a negative number inside a square root.

Comment: And that could be even if we let's say have limit to negative infinity of $\frac{x^3 * \sqrt{x^4}}{3x^7} = \frac{(-|x^3|)* (-1)|1/(x^7)|*\sqrt{x^4}}{3}$

Comment: And then we can put them inside the square root

Comment: In that case you do not need to put anything inside the square root. $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^3\cdot\sqrt{x^4}}{3x^7}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^2}{3x^4}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac1{3x^2}=0^+\;.$$

Comment: I understand, but if we would want to, we would have to make it into an absolute value right ?

Comment: Yes, we would have to.

Comment: But if we want to put $x^2$ inside a square root, then we can do it without absolute value, because it is positive anyways ?

Comment: Yes, if a term is positive, you can put inside a square root without absolute value.

Comment: If you want to put the terms inside the square root, you have to proceed as follows $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^3\cdot\sqrt{x^4}}{3x^7}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-\left|x^3\right|\sqrt{x^4}}{-3\left|x^7\right|}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-1}{-3}\sqrt{\frac{x^6\cdot x^4}{x^{14}}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac13\sqrt{\frac1{x^4}}= 0^+\;.$$

Answer (score 4):

There is a trap: as $x<0$, $$\sqrt{x^2+1}\sim -x.$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122974/discussion-on-answer-by-yves-daoust-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-fracx).